# Calculate client side MD5 hash of an image file to match one calculated by Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

Is there a method to calculate the MD5 of an image file on the client side in my Angular Map, that will match the MD5 when I store that file on Firestore?  I need to be able to confirm that a user file matches a reference version stored in firebase without having to upload it again.

I can get an array buffer from a file object on the local machine, but can't get the md5 calculation done locally to match what Firebase returns.

The result I got looks nothing like the md5 reported by Firebase, so I don't think I'm on the right track at all:

```
let file = target.files[0];
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
  data = event.target.result;
  let ret: any = data;
  if (data) {
    let len = ret.byteLength;
    let uintArBuff = new Uint8Array(ret);   //Does an array buffer convert to a Uint8Array?
    let md5 = new Md5();
    let hash = md5.appendByteArray(uintArBuff).end();  
    console.log(hash);
  }  
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

The above produced a result that looks like `29e10414c7c7b7adb61330b02f8f3ddc`, while
the MD5 reported by firebase is `KeEEFMfHt622EzCwL4893A==` so I think I'm up the wrong tree altogether.  Not even the same length hash.. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have commented but reputation doesn't allow me to.

`KeEEFMfHt622EzCwL4893A==` is base64 encoded. Yours is `hex` encoded.

I just used an online converted and it checks out that they match.

Comment: Extremely helpful thanks!